# Plotting spectral emissive power versus wavelength

Tags: plotting, physics

I am trying to plot a set of curves using the Planck distribution function for the following temperatures: `(2000,1000,400,100)K`. I attempted to do the following:

```
c1=3.742*10^8; 
c2=1.4388*10^4; 
EE1[x,2000]==c1/((x^5) (Exp[(c2/x 2000)]-1)); 
EE2[x,1000]==c1/((x^5) Exp[(c2/x 1000)]-1));
EE3[x,400]==c1/((x^5) Exp[(c2/x 400)]-1)); 
EE4[x,100]==c1/((x^5) Exp[(c2/x 100)]-1));

Plot[{EE1[x,2000],EE2[x,1000],EE3[x,400],EE4[x,100]},{x,10^-10,10^-4},PlotRangeAll];
```

When I try to run this code all I get is a grid with no plots. I know something is missing but I don't what.

Comment: Functions should be defined like this: `EE1[x_, 2000] := (* stuff *)`, but maybe it's better if you define it as a two-variable function…

Comment: Syntax correcting apart, there seem to be some issues with Overflow & Underflow with these kind of calculations. Try to rescale your problem.

Comment: Have a look [PlanckRadiationLaw](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlanckRadiationLaw.html) and [Black-Body Radiation Package](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/BlackBodyRadiation/guide/BlackBodyRadiationPackage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you looking for the spectral emissive power and [LogLogPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLogPlot.html):

```
c1 = 3.742*10^8;
c2 = 1.4388*10^4;
k = {2000, 1000, 400, 100};
e[λ_, T_] := c1/(λ^5 Exp[c2/(λ*T) - 1])
tab = Table[e[λ, T], {T, k}]
```

> $\left\{\frac{3.742\times 10^8 e^{1-\frac{7.194}{\lambda }}}{\lambda
> > ^5},\frac{3.742\times 10^8 e^{1-\frac{14.388}{\lambda }}}{\lambda
> > ^5},\frac{3.742\times 10^8 e^{1-\frac{35.97}{\lambda }}}{\lambda
> > ^5},\frac{3.742\times 10^8 e^{1-\frac{143.88}{\lambda }}}{\lambda
> > ^5}\right\}$

```
LogLogPlot[{Evaluate@tab}
, {λ, 0.1, 50}
, PlotRange -> {{0.2, 50}, {10^-4, 10^7}}
, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"
, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Besides the syntax issues, it looks like there is an error in your formula (the product x v should both be in the denominator).

```
c1 = 3.742*10^8;
c2 = 1.4388*10^4;
ee[x_, v_] := c1/((x^5 Exp[(c2/(x v))] - 1));
Plot[{ee[x, 2000], ee[x, 1500], ee[x, 1000]}, {x, 0, 10}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]